# Not showing the results i need

Tags: mysql, sql

I have this query

```
SELECT t1.ano, 
t1.mes,
t1.departamento_id, 
t1.departamento_nome, 
tempo_extra, 
tempo_ativo, 
tempo_extra/tempo_ativo AS volume_extra 
FROM ( 
SELECT 
YEAR(`data`) AS ano, 
MONTH(`data`) AS mes, 
departamentos.id AS departamento_id, 
departamentos.nome AS departamento_nome, 
SUM(tempo) AS tempo_extra 
FROM rh.aprovacoes LEFT JOIN rh.colaboradores ON colaboradores.id=aprovacoes.colaborador_id 
LEFT JOIN rh.departamentos ON departamentos.id=colaboradores.departamento_id
WHERE (tipo = 'BH' OR tipo = 'HE') AND (YEAR(aprovacoes.`data`)=2016 AND 
MONTH(aprovacoes.`data`)=2 AND colaboradores.departamento_id=2) OR 
(YEAR(aprovacoes.`data`)=2016 AND MONTH(aprovacoes.`data`)=1 AND colaboradores.departamento_id=2) 
GROUP BY colaboradores.departamento_id, MONTH(`data`) 
ORDER BY departamentos.nome ASC) AS t1 
LEFT JOIN ( 
SELECT YEAR(`data`) AS ano, 
 MONTH(`data`) AS mes, 
departamentos.id AS departamento_id, 
departamentos.nome AS departamento_nome, 
SUM(ativo) AS tempo_ativo 
FROM rh.processamento 
LEFT JOIN rh.colaboradores ON colaboradores.id=processamento.colaborador_id 
LEFT JOIN rh.departamentos ON departamentos.id=colaboradores.departamento_id 
 WHERE 1=1 AND (YEAR(processamento.`data`)=2016 AND MONTH(processamento.`data`)=2 AND colaboradores.departamento_id=2) OR (YEAR(processamento.`data`)=2016 AND MONTH(processamento.`data`)=1 AND colaboradores.departamento_id=2) 
GROUP BY colaboradores.departamento_id, MONTH(`data`)) AS t2 ON t1.departamento_id = t2.departamento_id 
ORDER BY ano ASC, mes ASC;
```

It's giving me this results:

```
ano mes departamento_id departamento_nome tempo_extra tempo_ativo volume_extra
2016 1     2            Administrativa    -73009      5562638     -0.0131
2016 1     2            Administrativa    -73009      6463516     -0.0113
2016 2     2            Administrativa    -198599     5562638     -0.0357
2016 2     2            Administrativa    -198599     6463516     -0.0307
```

But should be something like this:

```
ano mes departamento_id departamento_nome tempo_extra tempo_ativo volume_extra
2016 1     2            Administrativa    -73009      5562638     -0.0131
2016 2     2            Administrativa    -198599     6463516     -0.0307
```

What i'm doing wrong?

Comment: Look at "volume_extra" in your results. In each case, they are unique values, so that's why they are being pulled in. How are you deciding where you write "But should be something like this" which is the correct "volume_extra" record that you want? That's the key.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to join the two subqueries using their dates, not just the department IDs, so you don't get a cross-product of all the dates. So change the `ON` clause to

```
ON t1.departamento_id = t2.departamento_id AND t1.ano = t2.ano AND t1.mes = t2.mes
```